# If I click twice on the same position, then the heart icon shifts to the top left position of the screen

Tags: javascript

I want to build a simple click heart animation using JS. Whenever a user clicks anywhere in the screen a heart pops up from that particular point for 2 sec. It works, but if I click twice on the same position, the heart icon shifts to the top left position of the screen. Please help me to fix this bug. here is the link of my project - " https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wood-2k4gyp?file=/index.js "

```js
const wbody = document.querySelector("body");
const hearticon = document.querySelector(".heart")


wbody.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    hearticon.classList.add("active");

    console.log(e);

    let xValue = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
    let yValue = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;

    hearticon.style.left = `${xValue}px`
    hearticon.style.top = `${yValue}px`

    setTimeout(() => {

        hearticon.classList.remove("active");
    }, 2000);
    
});
```

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
}

.heart {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    /* left: 50%;
    right: 50%; */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 0;
}

.heart.active{
    animation: animate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 0px;
    }
    
    30%{
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
  
    50%{
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 60px;
    }

    70%{
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 50px;
    }

    80%{
        opacity: 1;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    90%{
        opacity: 0.3;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Click Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>


<body>

    <i class="fa-solid fa-heart heart"></i>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click first time everything is ok because `e.target` = document's body and it's fine.
But when you click second time `e.target` = heart icon.
In this case `e.clientX` becomes equal to `e.target.offsetLeft` (the same for clientY) and xValue and yValue are equal to 0.
That's why you have behaviour you mention.
I think you can remove subtraction `e.target.offsetLeft` from e.clientX (the same for Y) and it will work.

```
let xValue = e.clientX;
let yValue = e.clientY;
```

Comment: Now it's working properly ! Thank You for your help and beautiful explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the offsets (e.g. `e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft`), you can directly use [`e.offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [`e.offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) for `xValue` and `yValue`, respectively.

Comment: Now it's working properly! Thank You for your help and beautiful explanation!